# Migrate localDB to Remote database

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I have an old application, which i am moving to new server. I haven't worked on this application.

It is using localDB placed in app_data folder.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=database;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I wanted to shift database to sql server remote instance.
What is required to do this?

If i restore database from this file to sql server and make new connection string to that database. Will it work? or i need to do some more changes at application level.

Please guide me in this regard